# Is there a way to display the value of a javascript variable in the html code itself?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I want to be able to see a variable value in the html code itself rather than just the webpage once it loads.
I've tried this:

`document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "value";`

and while the value of the variable appears on the webpage, the html itself isn't changed.

Alternatively, is there a way to print a variable value in the javascript code?

Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <p id='value'>"random"</p>
</body>
<script  type ="text/javascript">
    var someValue = "something cool"
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = someValue;
</script>
</html>
```

Once the page loads, I want the body to look like this:

```
<body>
    <p id='value'>"something cool"</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the HTML code itself"?  The stuff you see from the browser "View Page HTML" will always be the HTML originally received. You will however see the actual DOM via the developer "DOM Inspector" tools.

Comment: You won't change the HTML itself, but if you look in your DevTools (Chrome, firebug, etc) you can see it in the translated DOM.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that there was a difference. It does appear in the DOM. Thanks!